# Some products have catalog/product/view/id/2221/name-of-the-product from product URL magento 2?

Tags: product, magento2.3.3, product-urls, magento-2.1.8, url-key

In the Site, product URL is like this: `http://www.test.com/product-url-key`

But when I searching the product then some product URLs are showing like this:

```
http://www.test.com/catalog/product/view/id/2221/product-url-key
```

This is not for all products.

i want to url like this type `http://www.test.com/product-url-key.html`

Comment: Please do reindex and test in incognito window (private window).

Comment: I have done Reindexing,  flush cache also

Comment: I had fixed the same issue today in M2.3.2

Comment: You can use this module to regenerate the Product URLs https://github.com/Iazel/magento2-regenurl

Comment: @VinodKumar you also check product visibility which I mention in below.

Answer (score 2):

> **Note: Please take a backup of the database**

To resolve this issue first delete the rows from the "url_rewrite" table which has 'product' as 'entity_type'.
You can use below query

```
DELETE FROM `url_rewrite` where entity_type='product'
```

Then install below the extension

> https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

and run the below command.

```
php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate --entity-type=product
```

This solution is worked for me, Hopefully, this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try/use [Regenerate a Url](https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites) rewrites extension.

The extension allows you to regenerate a Url rewrites of products and categories.

1 > Run command to re-generate Url rewrites for all categories/products for all stores:

```
php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate
```

2 > To regenerate Url rewrites for specific store view (e.g.: store view id is "1"):

```
php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate 1
```

Comment: This is really pathetic plugin take too much time but generate nothing

Comment: To the contrary, I've had good experiences using this module quite a few times. It _could_ work in this instance and not work in some others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Marketing > url rewrite > new url rewirte

Request Path  "product-url-key"

Target Path   "catalog/product/view/id/2221"

Redirect Type "no"

Save and flush cache

Or

Marketing > url rewrite

search with the "product-url-key" in Request path 
there you will get some idea.

Hope it might help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

**Solution 1-**

- **Marketing->URL Rewrite** search the URL and edit the **Request Path**.
  OR you also can do this from database
- Go to the database select the **url_rewrite** table search with the **"product-url-key"** in and change the **request_path** of the product.

**Solution 2-**

- Go to the database select the **url_rewrite** table search with the **"product-url-key"** in and delete the URL then go to the product and save, it will auto-generate the product URL.

Comment: so if user have 100k products so he have to spent 5000 hours approximately to update products one by one.

Comment: No, in that case, delete all the product URL from url_rewrite and go to catalog>category and save the category one by one it will auto-generate the product URL.

Comment: It will not generate try it for your satisfaction.

Comment: this was possible in M1 but not in M2 on which version you try it ?

Comment: I am using Magento 2.3.3, you have to change little bit URL of your main category and save, again correct the URL as previous and save again it will auto-generate URL

Comment: yes if I change it will definitely update it. So this is the solution I have 5000 categories once I update one category url incorrectly & after that again save it correctly. Indeed its correct solution thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use default magento feature URL rewrites for your concern

**Marketing->SEO & Search->URL rewite**

here you can create new rule for your particular URL.
eg:

1. request path->http://www.test.com/product-url-key.html
2. target path->http://www.test.com/catalog/product/view/id/2221/product-url-key

and you will good to  go.

dont forget to reindex and flush.